# if i want to sort a column by size in rstudio, how do i make sure that the associated values of the rows sort with the column?

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data.frame with 1200 rows and 5 columns, where each row contains 5 values of one person. now i need to sort one column by size but I want the remaining columns to sort with the column, so that one column is sorted by increasing values and the other columns contain the values of the right persons. ( So that one row still contains data from one and the same person)

```
    colnames(BAPlotDET) = c("fsskiddet", "fspiddet","avg", "diff","absdiff")
```

these are the column names of my data.frame and I wanna sort it by the column called "avg"

Comment: If your columns are all numeric, then `mtcars[ with(mtcars, order(cyl, -mpg)), ]` is a good example, as is the dplyr code `mtcars %>% arrange(cyl, desc(mpg))`. The former does not accept negative sorting on strings, but the latter uses `desc` to support sorting strings. (I see sample data is still an issue, C K.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please always provide us with a reproducible example such as below. The sorting of a data frame by default sorts all columns.

```
vector <- 1:3
BAPlotDET <- data.frame(vector, vector, vector, vector, vector)
colnames(BAPlotDET) = c("fsskiddet", "fspiddet","avg", "diff","absdiff")
  fsskiddet fspiddet avg diff absdiff
1         1        1   1    1       1
2         2        2   2    2       2
3         3        3   3    3       3

BAPlotDET <- BAPlotDET[order(-BAPlotDET$avg),]

> BAPlotDET
  fsskiddet fspiddet avg diff absdiff
3         3        3   3    3       3
2         2        2   2    2       2
1         1        1   1    1       1
```

Comment: I will, next time! Thank you!!

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory please mark it as accepted